# Java System.out output in Unicode

Tags: java, windows, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I'm currently working on a text-based game in Java, which is played in the command line interpreter.

The problem is, that I want to echo German umlaute (line `ü ö ä ß`) in the command line, which isn't supported in Windows-systems by default. However, I found a way to achieve this with a bunch of things:

- I changed the code-page to `65001` (using `chcp 65001`)
- I changed the font to `Console Lucida`
- I used a `PrintStream` with a UTF-8 encoding to print to the command
  line (in the Java-program).

After doing this, outputting UTF-8 characters on the command line works. But this isn't the default setup on every PC.

So I thought, I create a Batch file to start the game, which does the basic setup to enable the UTF-8 output. Changing the code-page and using a UTF-8 `PrintStream` is no problem, but changing the font is kind of tricky.

The font should be installed on every Windows since Windows XP SP2, so that shouldn't be a problem. Also, you can change the font by changing a registry entry, but this requires some privileges and is not an option.

I googled around but I didn't found any `font`-command. Is there a workaround to change the console-font?

Comment: I am sorry that instead of answering question I am asking mine. But how did you changed code-page? I personally was sure that windows command prompt does not support unicode.

Comment: Me too. I added it to the post.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check jscript/vbscript to perform this configuration. These are almost fully functional programming languages that can call ActiveX and WMI API. You can run these scripts using command cscript or wscript.

Comment: Problem with this is that the access to the scipt-host might be disabled on the computer (like here in school).

Comment: In this case you can do nothing. You cannot go against the permissions of OS. Why are you developing app. in text mode? Write GUI! But if this is homework or something like this and scripting host+ access to registry are disabled, just use "your own" java based command prompt window. I believe some googleing can give you a lot of links. If not implement yours simple command prompt. it is easy. Then just run your application into your own command prompt.

Comment: It's not homework, it's a school project. The encoding part has nothing to do with the project, but it would be nice to have UTF-8 on the console. I'm just searching for and easy way to set the consoles font.

Comment: Please note that Lucida Console font doesn't support all Unicode characters. Roughly, only those already available in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) are supported by the font (which "by coincidence" also covers those Germanic characters). For example Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, etc are NOT supported. If you want to go for full Unicode, rather create a Swing based app instead of a console based app. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#DevelopmentEnvironment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented a bit and you can achieve this without any scripting and without JNI: Lucida can be chosen by making a link to cmd.exe and editing the properties of that link.

I opened the link in a hex-editor to see that Lucide Console is chosen in there. The really fun thing is, that inside the link the absolute path to cmd.exe is encoded (which is D:\Win... on my system), and then i copied the link to another computer i have here to see if it magically also works there (Windows is on C-Drive on that computer) and it does: Windows fixes the absolute path to cmd.exe for you and the console that is opened on that computer is set to Lucida too.

Now all you need to open your program inside that console (and make it print in that console) all you need is a batch-file containing the name of the link-file (ending in .lnk which is hidden on most systems) followed by your program name, like so:

```
c.lnk t.exe
```

since you are using java i guess you would have to write something like:

```
c.lnk java sth.jar
```

I created a minimal example you can find here:

http://www.mediafire.com/?1yn40gsed3isjut

it contains:

- a minimal t.exe which just pops open a MessageBox (if you dont trust t.exe just open it in notepad or pedump and see it only calls MessageBox no other api-functions)
- the link c.lnk  to cmd.exe configured to use Lucida,   (the absolute path will be fixed by Windows on running it)
- the .bat file which calls t.exe through c.lnk

Comment: thanks in advance, i hope this really works on every box, i have only 2 comps here.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. When i execute the Batch, only the content gets echoed. I tried different encodings, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: so what did you change the .bat to? something like `c.lnk java sth.jar`?

Comment: To `c.lnk java -jar build.jar`. But I created my own implementation of a command-line in Swing. Thanks for the great answer any ways.